# Loop through a json response received from facebook graph api in c# and get the latest value. (then, store it in database in dot net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, facebook-graph-api, json.net, razor-pages

I'm using the graph API of facebook to get the permalink of facebook posts. But it seems the endpoint always returns an array of all the posted posts.

So, I need to take the response and loop through it and get only the latest value that is always the first pair in the response.

Here is the response I get using the graph explorer. I only need the first pair from data array i.e the permalink_url and the id so that I can store them separately in a database to embed posts in my website using the permalink.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/347775946439542/photos/a.348021906414946/358023508748119/?type=3",
      "id": "347775946439542_358023508748119"
    },
    {
      "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/347775946439542/photos/a.348021906414946/350654269485043/?type=3",
      "id": "347775946439542_350654269485043"
    },
    {
      "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/347775946439542/photos/a.348021906414946/350651839485286/?type=3",
      "id": "347775946439542_350651839485286"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "QVFIUlRGODNTaFZAueEUxQ2VvcHlrMUw1MGE0U0FCblhZAY1hVbFBGUHhHdXlrSkgzSm0tb05pSGpFOXBYVG9EcnN5T21sQTgtYy1jSjhrZAW9WYmg5YmpVMXpQWTRLUkQ3ZA05PcEZAjUTNyV2VuV05hRG8yVlBaa3pia3dFTVRLU05nU0pU",
      "after": "QVFIUlBHMG44ZAkxHdUsxb012bVlOQ0ZAfaDhHLUZA6VEt6MHd0QjJYZADlfZAVk2aExSdlJESUU2SlVDaVJsYzI4dnlmUllZASzhKd3Nkb09aa2ZAMRHZAFTGhMVHFoQ1hjNE5zNDJ2aV96UGtVQUpBeHE1b2xUTzk2SHZALLTZA1Y3pZAZAmJOMENS"
    }
  }
}
```

I did go through some questions on this that used newtonsoft but couldn't get it to work.
So any help on how to loop through this in C# (razor page) and then return them from a method. Thenafter I need to store both the permalink as well as the id in database.

Here is my method: Here _getPermalink has the endpoint I have to hit.

Also 'str' has the response which is shown below. I have to fetch the permalink and id from that.

```
public string GetPermalink()
        {

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Stream data = client.OpenRead(_getPermalink);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
            string str = "";
            str = reader.ReadLine();
            data.Close();

            return str;
        }
```

When I call this endpoint from the method:`string res = facebook.GetPermalink();` (Here facebook is just a constructor with values required for making the call to endpoint such as page id, access token,etc.)

The same response looks something like this.

```
{"data":[{"permalink_url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/347775946439542\/photos\/a.348021906414946\/358023508748119\/?type=3","id":"347775946439542_358023508748119"},{"permalink_url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/347775946439542\/photos\/a.348021906414946\/350654269485043\/?type=3","id":"347775946439542_350654269485043"},{"permalink_url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/347775946439542\/photos\/a.348021906414946\/350651839485286\/?type=3","id":"347775946439542_350651839485286"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"QVFIUlRGODNTaFZAueEUxQ2VvcHlrMUw1MGE0U0FCblhZAY1hVbFBGUHhHdXlrSkgzSm0tb05pSGpFOXBYVG9EcnN5T21sQTgtYy1jSjhrZAW9WYmg5YmpVMXpQWTRLUkQ3ZA05PcEZAjUTNyV2VuV05hRG8yVlBaa3pia3dFTVRLU05nU0pU
```

I'm relatively new with the concept of json object/arrays in C# and using newtonsoft. Any help and explanations are appreciated.
(PS: Is there a way to get the permalink and id of the Latest Posts ONLY, using the facebook graph api?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the JSON data you posted, you can get the first permalink URL from it using the following one-liner:

```
string permalinkUrl = (string)JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("data[0].permalink_url");
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SUgz51